# Custom Magento Meta Title

Tags: magento, title, meta, product

I'm using magento 1.9. On product pages the meta title is like

"PRODUCT NAME CATEGORY SUBCATEGORY"

I would like to show only "PRODUCTNAME - Mysite.com"

How can I make this fix only on product pages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento sets title tag in two different places. First in Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs inside _prepareLayout() method

```
    $title = array();
    $path  = Mage::helper('catalog')->getBreadcrumbPath();

    foreach ($path as $name => $breadcrumb) {
        $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb($name, $breadcrumb);
        $title[] = $breadcrumb['label'];
    }

    if ($headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')) {
        $headBlock->setTitle(join($this->getTitleSeparator(), array_reverse($title)));
    }
```

Content of $path variable will vary depending on how you got to the product page. For example:

Direct link to product:

- url: /aviator-sunglasses.html
- title: Aviator Sunglasses

Navigate to product using category menu:

- url: /accessories/eyewear/aviator-sunglasses.html
- title: Aviator Sunglasses - Eyewear - Accessories

And then in Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View inside _prepareLayout() method

```
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
    if ($title) {
        $headBlock->setTitle($title);
    }
```

Here it simply checks if meta title product attribute is set and overrides previously set title if so. So, you have two options:

1. Set meta title on every product
2. Rewrite _prepareLayout() method in Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs class

   ```
   if ($headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')) {
       if ($product = Mage::registry('current_product')) {
           $storeName = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/name');
           $pageTitle = $storeName ? $product->getName() . ' - ' . $storeName : $product->getName();
           $headBlock->setTitle($pageTitle);
       } else {
           $headBlock->setTitle(join($this->getTitleSeparator(), array_reverse($title)));
       }
   }
   ```